# SQL server date convertion

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to convert a varchar to date using the below code.

```
SELECT CAST('14/08/2018' as date) --This code does not work
SELECT CAST('09/08/2018' as date) --This code works
```

It appears that when the day part of the date gets to '13' that is where it starts breaking.Is there a logical explanation for this?

The error given is :

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 7670 
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Looks like your date format is set to MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: If you use default date format that won't happen: `2018-08-14`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should decide your date component before conversation :

I would considered date with style `dd/mm/yyyy` :

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '14/08/2018', 103)
```

However, it seems SQL has set date `mm/dd/yyyy`.

If so, you can change it :

```
set dateformat dmy
```

Comment: @TshepisoSelepe if this answer solved your problem, then please mark it as the correct answer by clicking on the check mark at the left.

Comment: Done.Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The cause of your problem is that you have a **mm/dd/yyyy** format and the first value is the month. You will either need to swap the first and the second value. You can use convert for this purpose with option 101, which converts a **mm/dd/yyyy** to a **mm/dd/yyyy**:

```
select convert(DATE, '14/08/2018', 101);
```

This is the US standard and this converts your `varchar` to a `DATE`. Now, if you want to display this in a format of **dd/mm/yyyy**, then just do

```
select convert(varchar(10), convert(DATE, '14/08/2018', 101), 103);
```